# Adding class to div if it has parent with same class

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

right now I'm working on Episerver webapp and Im new to vue.js so I need your help..
I need to detect accordion inside accordion so I can give it left margin thus indent, so its clear its accordion inside accordion and not just two accordions after one another.

current cshtml looks like this :

```
<generic-component inline-template class="vue-block-app" server-rendered="true" >
<div>
    <div v-bind:class="{isNested: isNested('@collapseId','collapsible-list-item-block')}" class="collapsible-list-item-block grid @Model.GetHiddenPrintClassName">
        <div class="collapsible-list-item-block__heading" id="headingOne" @@click="collapsibleClicked('@collapseId')">
            <div class="@collapseButtonClass" v-b-toggle="'@collapseId'" variant="primary">
                <div class="text-line-content">@Html.PropertyFor(m => m.Title)</div>
                <div class="icon-wrap float-right">

                    <span class="collapseIcon">@{Html.RenderCollapseIcon();}</span>
                    <span class="expandIcon">@{Html.RenderExpandIcon();}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <b-collapse id="@collapseId" @collapsedByDefault class="collapsible-list-item-block__content" style="display: none;">
                @Html.PropertyFor(m => m.Content)
        </b-collapse>
    </div>
</div>
```

my vue file looks like this:

```
<script>
import componentMounted from '../mixins/component-mounted';
export default {
    mixins: [componentMounted],
    data() {
        return {
            isNestedAccordion: false,

        };
    },
    computed: {

    },
    methods: {
        collapsibleClicked(id) {
            $(window).trigger("collapseClicked", [id]);
        },
        isNested(id, className) {
            var element = document.getElementById(id);
            do {
                if (element.classList && element.classList.contains(className)) {
                    console.log("true")
                    return true;
                }
                element = element.parentElement.parentElement;
            } while (element);
            console.log("false")
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and css class .isNested{margin-left:20px;}

what Im I doin wrong that Im not getting class to my div....
Btw, when I had my isNested() inside collapsibleClicked() it worked just fine on click... what am I missing?

Comment: Can't you just do `.collapsible-list-item-block > .collapsible-list-item-block { margin-left:20px; }`  in CSS?

Comment: Nope, ">"  selects nodes that are direct children of the first element. Which is not a case here. Just to be sure I've tried without success.

Comment: If you have intermediate classes, you can add them. Not sure if that helps

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Not sure if I understand.

Comment: If it's always `.collapsible-list-item-block > .something-else > .another-element > .collapsible-list-item-block { margin-left:20px; }` that'd be fine, too. You could even check, if just `.collapsible-list-item-block .collapsible-list-item-block { margin-left:20px; }` works in your case.

Comment: Unfortunattely thats not the case, as it can be another element in between... and also its not specified how many accordions will be nested. My bet is that there is issue with the :v-bind in my div because console.logs works fine. Im just not getting that class there.

Comment: So at the end you were right. .collapsible-list-item-block .collapsible-list-item-block { margin-left:20px; } works just fine. Im not sure what I was doing that it didnt work, maybe small vacation was needed. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: We've all been there. Glad, it helped :) You'r welcome